# Swift 2 if let with do-try-catch

Tags: swift

In Swift 1.2 I have this:

```
if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("some", ofType: "txt"),
       data = String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    for line in data.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()) {
        // Do something
    }      
} else {
    println("some.txt is missing")
}
```

In Swift 2, I can no longer do this, because both `pathForResource` and `contentsOfFile` can throw, as well as returning optionals. I can fix it, but it now seems remarkably verbose:

```
do {
    if let filePath = try NSBundle.... {
        do {
            if let data = try String.... {
                for line in data..... {
                    // Do something
                }
            } else {
                print("Nil data")
            }
        } catch {
            print("contentsOfFile threw")
        }
    } else {
        print("Nil pathForResource")
    }
} catch {
    print("pathForResource threw")
}
```

I expect I have missed something - any help appreciated.

Comment: just saw the keynote. i thought you can have multiple `try` statements in a `do` block. isn't that possible?

Comment: I haven't seen the keynote yet but it seems like Swift's feature set is expanding almost too rapidly.

Comment: You don't have to have a `catch` every time you use `try`. In fact, most of the time you probably shouldn't catch exceptions, and instead should just let them propagate upwards. See http://exceptionsafecode.com/ (It talks about C++, but after looking at Swift's exception model I think the principles apply to Swift as well.)

Comment: Swift's try/catch is quite simply the worst implementation I've ever seen. The whole idea of exceptions is that you want them to bubble up, but it appears Swift demands you catch them in the enclosing code, which, IMHO, violates the entire concept of what exceptions are for - out of band, non-local handlers.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz You can let them bubble up, but it's a bit more work than other languages. If `A()` throws, and `B` calls `A`, then as long as `B` `throws` and you `try A()`, all is well. You don't need to catch it in the enclosing call.

Comment: @Jedidja, I sort of consider that to be the same thing - one way or the other, having `A` throw means that anyone calling it has to do *something*. But as it turns out there is a solution, `try!`. This basically says "yes I know this thing my throw, but I don't care if it does". This is what I use almost universally now, although frankly I still don't see why we need to. It would be one thing if the throws were infrequently used and the `try` was only used here and there, but the API makes use of them all over the place.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Yeah ... I don't really know what they were trying to do. Re-reading the documentation where they mention that "exceptions are not like other languages and should be treated as return codes" doesn't really help either. Maybe there's some construct from functional programming I'm missing though?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use guard syntax instead of if-let.

Here is a sample:

```
do {

    guard let filePath = try NSBundle .... else {
        // if there is exception or there is no value
        throw SomeError
    }
    guard let data = try String .... else {
    }

} catch {

}
```

The difference between if-let and guard is scope of the unwrapped value. If you use if-let filePath value is available only inside the if-let block. If you use guard filePath value is available to scope that is guard called in.

Here is the relevant section in swift book

> A guard statement, like an if statement, executes statements depending
>   on the Boolean value of an expression. You use a guard statement to
>   require that a condition must be true in order for the code after the
>   guard statement to be executed. Unlike an if statement, a guard
>   statement always has an else clause—the code inside the else` clause
>   is executed if the condition is not true.

Comment: Haven't been able to try it yet, but that makes sense. I couldn't see anything in the docs that said it was ok to have multiple `try`s in the same do-catch, but that will do it! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Near as I can tell, only your String initializer in the above actually throws an error (although `pathForResource()` may change from returning an optional value to throwing an error at some point). Therefore, the below should replicate what you did before:

```
if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("some", ofType: "txt") {
    do {
        let data = try String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        for line in data.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()) {
                // Do something
        }
    } catch {
        print("Couldn't load the file somehow")
    }
} else {
    print("some.txt is missing")
}
```

Your string is no longer optional, so there's no need for an `if let` there.

As mustafa points out, a `guard` statement could be used to remove a level of indentation in the success case:

```
guard let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("some", ofType: "txt") else {
    print("some.txt is missing")
}
do {
    let data = try String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    for line in data.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()) {
        // Do something
    }
} catch {
    print("Couldn't load the file somehow")
}
```

Now, if `pathForResource()` changed from returning an optional to throwing an error, you can simply use these try statements in sequence:

```
do {
    let filePath = try NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("some", ofType: "txt")
    let data = try String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    for line in data.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()) {
        // Do something
    }
} catch {
    print("some.txt is missing")
}
```

The first statement to throw an error will kick out at that point, preventing execution of anything past that. A single catch statement is enough to pick up anything from a series of failable operations, which makes it easy to chain them.

Comment: In the final example, how would one update the catch clause to more accurately describe the error, since we can no longer say that "some.txt is missing" (perhaps it was `contentsOfFile:encoding:` that threw)? Or are we limited to some generic "Something went wrong" message?

Comment: @BenPackard - Because both of the error-throwing lines kick back an NSError, the implicit `error` parameter that comes in with the catch statement can be safely cast to an NSError and examined. You could either present an error to the user directly using that NSError (probably not the most descriptive), or you could pull the error code and domain out of it and build your own error report based on the exact error you were getting back. You could handle all the error cases from either of the failable operations.

Comment: I see - and presumably if another throwing function was added which returned some NSErrorType instead of an NSError, that could be handled in another catch statement (or one per each type). Thanks.

Comment: @BenPackard - Yes, I commonly do this using `catch let error as [custom error type] {` statements to group the specific error types you may get back.